# Sharing Jupyter Notebook/Lab output with not technical people

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I am looking for suggestions, I would like to share my Jupyter Notebook/Lab analysis with not technical people inside my organisation, ideally I would like to share only the output and not the code, for example through Voila. I am also planning to update the analysis daily, therefore I would like to avoid updating manually the code. I read few articles about JupyterHub and Dockerand they seem the best direction, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: A question like that might be best answered on https://discourse.jupyter.org/. As a refinement of what you already proposed (and what seems fine to me), see [voila-gallery](https://blog.jupyter.org/a-gallery-of-voil%C3%A0-examples-a2ce7ef99130) as an example of how to set-up voila with The Littlest JupyterHub (basically JupyterHub stripped down for use-cases like yours). Not adding it as an answer as it is not really an alternative, just a refinment of your own idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) is an open-source tool that converts Jupyter Notebook into shareable web applications. You can add widgets to the notebook with YAML header. Widgets are connected with variables in the code, so no need to change the notebook itself. There is an `show-code` parameter in the YAML that you can use to hide the code. To run notebook daily you can set `schedule` parameter with crontab-like time interval definition for automatic execution.

##### The example notebook with YAML header

[image: Jupyter Notebook with YAML header for Mercury framework]

The YAML header:

```yaml
---
title: My notebook
description: Notebook with plot
show-code: False
params:
    name:
        input: text
        label: What is your name?
        value: Piotr
    points:
        input: slider
        label: How many points?
        value: 200
        min: 10
        max: 250
---
```

##### The web application from notebook

[image: web app from notebook]

You can read more in the article [how to share notebook with non-programmers](https://mljar.com/blog/share-jupyter-notebook/).

The framework is created on top of the [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/). It can be easily deployed on any machine with Python. The deployment to Heroku can be done with two commands, for other providers there is a `docker-compose` available. You can check details in the [docs](https://mercury-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploy/deployment/).

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I'm a bit biased because I work at Deepnote.*

We're building a tool to help you do that - check out https://deepnote.com
You can run the notebook there (or just upload it), and just share the link with the less technical people the same way you would do with Google Docs. They'll be able to immediately see any changes you make. You can also schedule it to re-run daily.

There's a way to hide the code (CMD/CTRL + P, then Hide code), and we're planning some more ways to present data soon.

Let me offer some alternatives as well:

- [Hosted notebook solutions](https://datasciencenotebook.org/): Binder, Colab or Hex
- [Dashboarding tools](https://pyviz.org/dashboarding/index.html) (not necessarily a notebook view): Streamlit, Voila, Dash, Panel

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Curvenote](https://curvenote.com) it's aimed at exactly this problem and integrates directly with Jupyter.

You can use [it's chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jupyter-versioning-commen/egkbkefajoeehbmjgelpmdnpgnleknka?hl=en) to save versions of your notebooks, with outputs and then view [nbviewer](https://github.com/jupyter/nbviewer) style renderings these in the Curvenote web app. You then get a collaborative google doc style editor where you can include only the outputs, with supporting text/analysis if you need it, and share that.

The automation features for daily runs you'd be able to setup around Jupyter and Docker as you mention (Note not JupyterHub for your use case) and use the [python library / cli](https://pypi.org/project/curvenote/) to push updates to Curvenote.